# Getting "method undefined" when it is CLEARLY defined in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, undefined

I have a very simple bit of code (relies on jQuery):

```
var dom_builder = function() {

    this.table = function(elem,attributes) {
        return $("<table>").attr(attributes).appendTo(elem);
    }

};

console.log(dom_builder.table);
```

Now when I try to run it I get the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'table'**

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I get this error. I have used methods this way countless times before, without any issues..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(new dom_builder().table);
```

Comment: you need parenthesis, like `console.log(new dom_builder().table())` for this to work

Comment: @cambraca Anurag's syntax is valid. It's all about what you're trying to demonstrate, and I think he wanted to show that the function does exist using this syntax.

Comment: @Adam Backstrom it's valid, but it won't work as expected. It will return the function, instead of the function result, which is what is required, no?

Comment: Thanks! Totally my own fault, that'll teach me for copying old code.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var dom_builder = {

    "table": function(elem,attributes) {
        return $("<table>").attr(attributes).appendTo(elem);
    }

};
```

Comment: Nice, totally different approach and it works without having to initiate the function as recommended below :) Nice

Answer (score 1):

`dom_builder.table` doesn't exist until the function is run.

```
console.log(dom_builder.table); // undefined
d = new dom_builder();
console.log(d.table); // function(elem, attributes) { ... }
```